# Can't drive stepper motor (42BYG) with a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

The end goal is to make a chess board that moves the pieces by itself with help of a plotter. We already got most of the software. We only need to make the plotter work but we are having trouble with the stepper motor.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
 
in1 = 17
in2 = 18
in3 = 27
in4 = 22                                                                                            
#17 18 27 22 - vibrates
#18 17 27 22 - nothing
#17 18 22 27 - nothing
#18 17 22 27 - nothing
#22 27 18 17 - nothing
#27 22 18 17 - nothing

# careful lowering this, at some point you run into the mechanical limitation of how quick your motor can move
step_sleep = 0.002
 
step_count = 4096 # 5.625*(1/64) per step, 4096 steps is 360°
 
direction = True # True for clockwise, False for counter-clockwise
 
# defining stepper motor sequence (found in documentation http://www.4tronix.co.uk/arduino/Stepper-Motors.php)
step_sequence = [[1,0,0,0],
                 [1,1,0,0],
                 [0,1,0,0],
                 [0,1,1,0],
                 [0,0,1,0],
                 [0,0,1,1],
                 [0,0,0,1],
                 [1,0,0,1]]
 
# setting up
GPIO.setmode( GPIO.BCM )
GPIO.setup( in1, GPIO.OUT )
GPIO.setup( in2, GPIO.OUT )
GPIO.setup( in3, GPIO.OUT )
GPIO.setup( in4, GPIO.OUT )
 
# initializing
GPIO.output( in1, GPIO.LOW )
GPIO.output( in2, GPIO.LOW )
GPIO.output( in3, GPIO.LOW )
GPIO.output( in4, GPIO.LOW )
 
 
motor_pins = [in1,in2,in3,in4]
motor_step_counter = 0 ;
 
 
def cleanup():
    GPIO.output( in1, GPIO.LOW )
    GPIO.output( in2, GPIO.LOW )
    GPIO.output( in3, GPIO.LOW )
    GPIO.output( in4, GPIO.LOW )
    GPIO.cleanup()
 
 
# the meat
try:
    i = 0
    for i in range(step_count):
        for pin in range(0, len(motor_pins)):
            GPIO.output( motor_pins[pin], step_sequence[motor_step_counter][pin] )
        if direction==True:
            motor_step_counter = (motor_step_counter - 1) % 8
        elif direction==False:
            motor_step_counter = (motor_step_counter + 1) % 8
        else: # defensive programming
            print( "uh oh... direction should *always* be either True or False" )
            cleanup()
            exit( 1 )
        time.sleep( step_sleep )
 
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    cleanup()
    exit( 1 )
 
cleanup()
exit( 0 )
```

Here's the setup:

[image: here's the setup]

The stepper motor should make a full 360 rotation but it just stays still but sometimes it vibrates, which we think means the negatives are wrong but we are not sure since its very inconsistent

We tried changing the pins but with no success. We also tried using a different stepper motor (28BYJ-48) to see if that one would work and it actually did. We think that maybe we connected the different GPIO from the stepper motor incorrectly since we don't really know which of them is positive and which one is negative.  We only know that the red is connected with blue in some way and green is connected with black. We looked at the datasheet and it just confused us more, so we decided to see if we could get an answer here.

Comment: 28BYJ-48 is a unipolar stepper and 42BYG is a bipolar stepper. Where is your schematic of the driver and the motor connections?

Comment: (1) I think L298N only drives bipolar stepper. (2) Start with 5kHz and go down, usually motor starts shaking below 1kHz.

Comment: maybe also switch away from the positively ancient L298N, it's very inefficient, i.e., you need much more input voltage / power than reaches your motor, and the difference is converted to heat in the L298N. If insufficient power supply turns out to be a problem here, you could calculate if using a lower-loss motor driver would make the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with this project is the lack of design specs for your "plotter".

This results in the accidental mismatch of all important interface requirements such as Torque/gear ratio, voltage, current, unipolar vs bipolar drivers and same with motors.

Darlington NPN open collector drivers are unipolar and BJT , CMOS full Bridges are bipolar.   When motors have a RED centre tap, that means each end is grounded to 0 with a unipolar switch to conduct current.  Bipolar Bridges are low impedance at both voltages 0 & V+ so with two drivers per floating coil they can be same voltage (0) , + or - (bipolar)

I can suggest that CMOS 12V 2A bipolar bridge "CNC shields" work best for RPi's and Gcode scanner for Windows with Gcode run code for RPi permits optimal servo control by higher level code, user button or programmable Gcode files but without knowing your user and man-machine interface design specs, will not speculate.